# UITabBar's font distorts or gets squished after opening up a UIImagePickerController and returning back to view

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbar

[image: Before opening UIImagePickerController]

[image: After closing/returning from UIImagePickerController]

I am having a very strange thing happen with my iOS application wherein the font appears normal on my UITabBarButtons initially, but once I open up a modal dialog and close it, the tab bar buttons label's appear squished together. This happens when I open up either a UIImagePickerController or a custom modal dialog. I am consistently able to reproduce this issue. I even used a program called Reveal to see what's happening with the UITabBarButtons and the label inside of them, but I cannot see any difference in the view's before and after properties. I am compiling this for the latest release of iOS 7. I can reproduce this both in the simulator and on the device. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code which you used to create UITabBarButtons.

Comment: I used Interface Builder to layout the tabbar, it's constrained to the bottom of the view controller. I used to be using a UITabBarViewController, and I occasionally saw this issue when I used that as well, but only recently figured out that modals were causing this to happen. So basically, I'm not doing anything manual to layout the tabbar. It's all IB generated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running in to this and haven't found a solution. :(

Comment: I have this same issue.... If you solved it can you please post your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[urtabbar setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

Comment: Hmmm, this wasn't the exact answer, but when I went ahead and pinned the width to the view controller in IB, it seems to have fixed it at first glance. Need to do further testing though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my custom "CustomTabBarController" with a UITabBar I had to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` in the ViewDidLoad. This seemed to have fixed the squished text.